# COleDateTimeSpan dates difference returns incorrect value sometimes

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mfc, coledatetime

I am using the following code to find the difference between two dates basically one is current system date and another server date. I am getting different values at different times, hence I changed the format to only include dates and not datetimes. But still the difference of values remains the same issue. Issue as mentioned in the src line comments.

```
//dtHigher retrieved from a file from Server

COleDateTime datetimetmp = COleDateTime::GetCurrentTime();
CString strhigherDt = dtHigher.Format(_T("%d/%m/%Y")); //12/07/2022
CString strcurrentDt = datetimetmp.Format(_T("%d/%m/%Y")); //07/07/2022
COleDateTime dateHigher, dateCurrent;
dateHigher.ParseDateTime(strhigherDt);
dateHigher.ParseDateTime(strcurrentDt);
COleDateTimeSpan spanDays = dateHigher - dateCurrent;
CString strdatespan = spanDays.Format(_T("%D.%H.%M.%S")); //this gives some times 4.23.59.59, some times 5.00.00.00

int daysRem = (int) ::ceil(spanDays.GetTotalDays()); //based on above return value, its either 4 or 5
```

Comment: `\\this gives some times 4.23.59.59, some times 5.00.00.00` probably rounding error.

Comment: Unless you have a specific reason to use `COleDateTime`, see whether you can use [`std::chrono`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono) instead. It was introduced with C++11, so you might want to check whether VS 2010 has just enough support to use it.

Comment: @drescherjm Thanks for the comment. Any suggestion how do I fix this rounding error? Is this related to system current datetime stamp?

Comment: @IInspectable Thanks for the comment. Unfortunately I cannot use C++11 stuff as currently the support is only for C++98!

Comment: That's too bad. Still, the issue will be the same: You're calculating the difference between two timestamps taken at different times. The difference is rarely going to be an exact multiple of an hour. The solution is very likely different from what you think: Use UTC everywhere, and only ever convert to local time in the user interface. Once that is done, you'll no longer find a reason to calculate the difference between a client's local time and the server's local time (which, apparently, is at the core of the issue).

Comment: As I just checked via debugging found that the timestamp of hour.min.sec is same for the both the variables. Sometimes I think current system date time stamp is higher than the Server variable and hence the lower value of 4.xx instead of 5.00? I will try the UTC way, but not sure what's the impact of this on the application!

Comment: I believe internally it uses a floating point number which can cause these types of issues.

Comment: Indeed, `COleDateTime` is a wrapper for a `DATE` `VARIANT`. It uses a double-precision floating point value, where a value of `1.0` represents one day, with fractional parts storing hours, minutes, seconds, ... A consequence of this is that it's not possible to accurately represent time points, and, consequently calculate the exact distance between two points in time. As for the values you see in a debugger, those aren't the raw values, but rather converted to human-readable format. The conversion is lossy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello I was able to solve it by getting the date, month and year separately from COleDateTime class and getting the difference manually. Thanks for all the help.